# sequencediagram pushes text out of page

Tags: tikz-uml, pgf-umlcd, pgf-umlsd

I am using LLNCS2E format.In my paper, I am using a sequencediagram something like below. The text around it include itemized text.

```
itemized-text
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{sequencediagram}
            ::::    ::::
        \end{sequencediagram}
     }
\end{figure}
itemized-text
```

When I use 0.5 in resizebox, the page renders with sequencediagram at top with very tiny seqencediagram text in it and with other itemized-text below it in the same page.

When I use 0.6 in resizebox, the page renders with a slightly bigger sequencediagram text but with lots of empty space above and below it (all itemized-text gets pushed to the next page).

How to use empty space when I use 0.6 in resizebox? Is there any margin setting which I have to set so that I can align the sequencediagram at top and brings some itemized-text in below part of the page.

Comment: Why the `figure` environment, when you don't have a caption?

Comment: That said, it's a bit hard to fully understand what's going on without a complete example, you could try `\begin{figure}[hbt]`, but that's just a wile guess.